# how can I get gpg to list only my keys?

Tags: gpg

I would like to query gpg to list only the keys that I own on my local keyring. How is this done? I can see all keys by doing

```
gpg list-keys
```

-- that shows all the keys. I want just my keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have private keys on your machine only for your keys, you could do with listing private keys with

```
gpg --list-secret-key
```

This will show you only keys that have a private counterparts.

Otherwise, you can list either all or single key.